# Nagiosgraph - Access Forbidden

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nagios, httpforbiddenhandler

I have installed Nagiosgraph. When i go to browse the `http://server//nagiosgraph/` I get

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /nagiosgraph/cgi-bin/show.cgi on
>   this server.

System is 
Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1 LTS
Nagios 4.0.7
nagios-plugins-1.4.15
nagiosgraph-1.4.4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

One of the comments in this blog solved the problem: http://www.linuxfunda.com/2013/04/02/steps-to-configure-nagiosgraph-with-nagios-core/

> Bakyt on October 20, 2014 at 10:16 am said:
>
> After editing the apache2.conf this section:
>
> Options FollowSymLinks AllowOverride None Require all denied
>
> i just replaced “denied” with “granted”
>
> i am now able to see
>   http://NAGIOS_IP/nagiosgraph/cgi-bin/showconfig.cgi

Answer (score 0):

Update the permission of web-server user to access nagiosgraph directory, And check Apache error logs file if you are still getting the same issues.